# SSL using RSAL Toolkit not encapsulated by a jar Error

Tags: java, ssl, rsa

I'm running a 3rd party app which fails with the following stacktrace when trying to create a SSL connection to a server:

The root exception is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Toolkit not encapsulated by a jar.
    at com.rsa.jcm.f.hq.a(Unknown Source)    
    at com.rsa.jcm.f.jg.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.crypto.jcm.ModuleLoader.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.crypto.jcm.ModuleLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

Has anyone seen this occur when connecting over SSL that uses RSA? I've worked the google and there isn't anything obvious as to why this would happen.

This particular error happens on a Mac, and I've got a windows version of the same app which works correctly. Main difference being they bundle the JRE in the windows version, so I checked various security policies etc but there are no great differences in the JRE on windows vs the JRE on my mac.

The full stacktrace looks like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Problem loading module.
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.ju.g(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.ju.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.gd.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.dm.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.dm.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.me.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:845)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1348)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.<init>(CipherBox.java:175)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.newCipherBox(CipherBox.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.newCipher(CipherSuite.java:467)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:507)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:485)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:190)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:342)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:300)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:576)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:512)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:73)
    at com.somevendor.client.common.spring.remoting.http.e.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at com.somevendor.client.common.spring.remoting.http.SecureHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executePostMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:140)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:142)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Toolkit not encapsulated by a jar.
    at com.rsa.jcm.f.hq.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.jcm.f.jg.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.crypto.jcm.ModuleLoader.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.crypto.jcm.ModuleLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: Ok so I figured this out. It turns out I had a space in the path to the jar file I was executing, which seems to make the RSA toolkit blow up. So the answer to this is to make sure there are no spaces in the path (This is on a Mac, I could replicate the error on linux)

Comment: Can also confirm this happens on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering as I worked it out (5 years ago..). This exception happens when there is whitespace in the fully qualified path to the jar file that is been executed.

So this works:

```
/Users/stringy05/app/app.jar
```

But if you use a path with a space:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/stringy05/app/app.jar
```

Then it fails. When this originally happened I had a soft link in /Users/stringy05 to another hard disk, so either java or the OS was resolving the link path to the real path and it would fail.